# Not able to pull/push the code from Git after uninstalling the Docker

Tags: git, docker

I'm not able to pull/push the code from Git repository after uninstalling Docker.

**Details**:
Recently I have installed Docker CE, latest version in my Windows 10 and worked on creating the image the project I have worked on. Before that I have followed some examples and created the sample images. While doing so and before, I was able to pull/push the code from/into the Git repository.
After the creation of image and it's related scripts are done, I have uninstalled the Docker. Now I'm not able to access the Git repository. Below is the error message I'm getting.
Error:

**`fatal: unable to access 'http://<host_ip>/RnDProjects/SampleAuth.git/': Failed to connect to localhost port 4000: Connection refused`**

I'm suspecting that, when I'm doing the sample images creation when docker installed, I have ran a command for opening/allowing port 4000 to access the sample application. Below is the command.
**Command**:

```
$ docker run -d -p 4000:80 friendlyhello
```

**Link referred**:

[Docker Sample application run command](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/#run-the-app)

I'm suspecting that when I ran this command something happened and when I uninstalled that thing was not undone. Looks like the  port i.e., **4000**, is marked/used for something. I'm not able to pull/push the code from Git repository.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the git command?

Comment: It's a basic pull command.

`git pull --progress -v`

Comment: What git server were you using for the project? It looks like you were using a server inside the docker image, so it is not accessible anymore once you stopped it.

Comment: Server: **GitLab**

Comment: Do you mean gitlab.com, or a local instance? The error message shows git trying to connect to the port 4000, which was pointing to the docker machine. Could you check with `git remote -v` which remote are you using, and if it is a docker ip (such as 172.17.x.x), or a public one (such as gitlab.com)? I'm guessing you were using a Docker-hosted gitlab instance, which is now stopped.